# Excel 2010 Bar in Pie Chart - Points in Pie and in Stack Bar (Excel or VBA)

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-charts, vba

I am trying to achieve a very specific format for a Bar in Pie Chart in Excel 2010.  I need the points that are aggregated in the Pie Chart and displayed individually in the Stack Bar to display in the Pie Chart as well. In other words, show the points individually (no aggregation) in the Pie Chart as well as the Stack Bar individually. I have attached a workbook with the format I am trying to achieve.

Please keep in mind the chart you see in my workbook is just visual and is not dynamic.

I consider myself fluent in Excel and VBA but have never had this much trouble trying to achieve a particular format for a chart.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Bar of Pie Stack Overflow Example.xlsm](https://arlcap.box.com/shared/static/os9bf56fi0dp7ptzxzh71447c00qradf.xlsm)

Comment: Screenshots will go 1000x farther than your macro enabled workbook. I can guarantee noone is going to download that. Shoot a screenshot out to imgur and include a link here. Someone can come along with enough points to add the pic directly to your question.

Comment: And... do you mean "Bar AND Pie chart" or is it correct that this is a "Bar IN Pie chart"?